# Pod install installs pod from wrong spec repository

Tags: cocoapods, podfile

We created a private pod called ListKit und put it into our private cocoapods repository.

The Cocoapod Documentation says:

> "The order of the sources is relevant. CocoaPods will use the highest version of a Pod of the first source which includes the Pod (regardless whether other sources have a higher version)."

We included both spec sources on top of the Podfile like so:
(our own repo is the first on the list)

```
source 'ssh://git@stash.mycompany:7999/customspec.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

For some reason ListKit of the Cocoapods Master Spec Repository will be used if i run
pod install
instead of the ListKit from our private spec repository.

Is this intentional or a bug?

I use Cocoapods Version: 1.5.3
on Mac OS 10.13.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the doc at https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod. You can directly set an individual source for a specific pod to disambiguate this situation:

```
pod 'ListKit', :source => 'ssh://git@stash.mycompany:7999/customspec.git'
```

As for why it is originally fetching from the second repository instead of the first repository, it may be a bug, or it may be that another pod using the Master Spec Repository had a dependency on 'ListKit', or it may be that no pod matching the requirements of 'ListKit' could be found in the first repo.

Comment: I also opened an issue on github and it seems, that this really is a bug. 
Using the source parameters seems legit. Totally forgot about it.

Comment: Issue that @SebastianBoldt is referring to: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8079

Comment: @SebastianBoldt: _This issue will be auto-closed because there hasn't been any activity for a few months._